# How to adjust the height of UIView added as UITableViewController header

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview, storyboard

I dragged a UIView to header of UITableView of UITableViewController , this view works pretty well as a header to table, but has abnormal height , its all done inside a storyboard, I want to know how I can control its height. Whatever height I set in Storyboard it doesn't affect , it always shows same height. See the attached image the gray part is UIView as a header.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of headers in UITableView

1. UITableView header
2. UITableView Section headers

Assuming you are talking about the first case.

**Static Header View Height**

If your header has static height and it is placed in the sotrybaord inside the Table View, you can provide height in the size inspector.

[image]

**Dynamic Header View Height**

If your header height is dynamic you need to go for programmatic approach.

1. Create a header, with all subview with their constraints, connect it to you headerView property in the Table View Controller.
2. Create a method `updateSizeForHeaderView` that will update the header view height based on the tableview width and the content inside the header.
3. Call you `updateSizeForHeaderView` from `viewWillLayoutSubviews` so that on rotation of screen our header view is updated.
4. In `viewDidLoad` set you header `tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView`

Thats all.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var headerView : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        updateSizeForHeaderView(inTableView: tableView)
    }

    func updateSizeForHeaderView(inTableView tableView : UITableView) {
        let size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(tableView.frame.size, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow)
        headerView.frame.size = size
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 5
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell_ID", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I placed a UILabel inside it and anchored it to UIView using contraints and laos height constrain but still same result

Comment: alright so i need UIView inside UiView to achieve this

Comment: I wonder I did exactly what you tried but didnt work, I am using UITableViewController FYI

Comment: I have static height and fixed contents , and I have set the height in SB problem is that height attribute isn't honored .

Comment: @vishal Share a storyboard, with the your UITableViewController Scene

Comment: this results in the table to messed up, its even visible on the gif... some cells are under the header, which can be fixed by reloading the table, but the scrolling will mess up to

Comment: @PeterLapisu, Yes but this can be fixed with setting contentOffset = current content offset + change in the height of the header, just after calling `updateSizeForHeaderView `. Basically displacing the whole content by same amount as the change in the height of header.

Comment: you should not mess up the contentOffset for this

Comment: Agreed, as answered by you, resetting the header view is a better approach to fix offset issues

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @BangOperator answer, you need to reassign the header on the table view afterward, or you may encounter strange behavior... this forces the table view to a proper update

```
...  
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize lastTableViewHeaderSize;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL tableViewHeaderSizeChanged;

@end


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    CGSize size = [self.tableView.tableHeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:self.tableView.bounds.size withHorizontalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired verticalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow];

    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(size, self.lastTableViewHeaderSize)) {

        CGRect frame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
        frame.size = size;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = frame;
        self.tableViewHeaderSizeChanged = YES;

    }

}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (self.tableViewHeaderSizeChanged) {
        self.tableViewHeaderSizeChanged = NO;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}
```

Comment: i doubt as this is not section header this is tableview header

Comment: Please try this int `viewDidLoad` self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

Comment: You can set different header height for each section. Doesn't matter if you only have 1 section.

Comment: @MuratTezyapar i have said it clearly in post, its not Table section header, this is UITableView header which appears above the TableView

Comment: @vishal YouStoryboard.storyboard > YouViewController > Attributes inspector > Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets.

Comment: @vishal please try my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please do following might help to you.
[image]

Via programmatically

> self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

**EDITED**

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-36, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @vishal Now set the `UIEdgeInsetsMake `.

Comment: That basically shifts the table under the view doest adjusts the height of UiView